# How to use struct module to convert 64 bit addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python's `struct` module I'm able to convert 32-bit addresses quite nicely:

```
rp = struct.pack("<L", 0x565555c7)
# b'\xc7UUV'
```

But when I try this for 64-bit addresses:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
struct.error: 'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

So how could I use the struct library if at all? What other methods are available for packing 64 bit addresses?

Comment: Because "'L' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295"

Comment: You need to specify the type code for a "long long" 8 byte integer as shown in the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) **not** the one for "unsigned long" 4 byte integers.

Answer (score 4):

`int` has a method to do this for you:

```
>>> 0x565555c7.to_bytes(8, 'big')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00VUU\xc7'
```

`to_bytes` produces a `bytes` value given a the number of bytes you want and the endianness. Compare

```
# 4 bytes instead of 8
>>> 0x565555c7.to_bytes(4, 'big')
b'VUU\xc7'

# 4 bytes, but little-endian instead of big-endian
>>> 0x565555c7.to_bytes(4, 'little')
b'\xc7UUV'
```

Answer (score 2):

`L` is for 4-byte (32-bit) unsigned integers; `Q` is for 8-byte (64-bit) unsigned integers.